# Parse escaped json string in Golang

Tags: json, string, go, escaping

Say I have this json string:

```
{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\",\"D\":2,\"E\":\"e\"}
```

I want to convert above string into struct:

```
{
  A string
  B string
  C string
  D int
  E string
}
```

Im not sure how to do that as I have do the quote and unquote but seems no success yet.

Comment: What are the quoting rules for the string? The answer depends on the quoting used.  For example, if the string is JSON encoded JSON, then unmarshal twice.  If the string uses Go quoting, use strconv.Unquote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your incoming string before unquoting it like this:

```
s,err := strconv.Unquote(`"`+yourstring+`"`)
```

Then you can proceed with unmarshalling it.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat of a hack, but the input string is how it would be encoded if it was in a JSON object, so you can do this:

```
x:=json.RawMessage(`"{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\",\"D\":2,\"E\":\"e\"}"`)
var v string
err:=json.Unmarshal(x,&v)
var x MyStruct
json.Unmarshal([]byte(v),&x)
```

Comment: i got error: `invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string`

Comment: I used a package where the function accept string as param, I read that param receiving this escaped json, convert it to rawmessage, unmarshall and got that error.

Comment: Raw message is []byte. It might've been easier to remove the backslashes.

Comment: you can try this when `strconv.Unquote` not work(got invalid syntax),  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Unquote` method of `strconv` as suggested by mfathirirhas, I have created a small code depicting you scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type response struct {
    A string
    B string
    C string
    D int
    E string
}

func main() {

    str := (`"{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\",\"D\":2,\"E\":\"e\"}"`)
    fmt.Printf(str)
    s, err := strconv.Unquote(str)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(s, err)
    var resp response
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &resp); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)

}
```

Output:

```
"{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\",\"D\":2,\"E\":\"e\"}"
{"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c","D":2,"E":"e"} <nil>
{a b c 2 e}
```